# Spring mvc controller mapping error (404error)

Tags: java, spring, jsp, http-status-code-404

There is a 404 error when I execute my application.

I can see the view when I excute first one below, but second one is not possible.

http://localhost:8091/cboard

http://localhost:8091/listPage

Please let me know what is problem. (I need second one..)

The controller:

```
@RequestMapping("/cboard", method=RequestMethod.GET)
public String list(Model model,HttpServletRequest req) throws Exception{

   req.getSession().getAttribute("clientMemberVO");
   model.addAttribute("list", service.listAll());
   List<BoardVO> list = service.listCriteria(cri);


    return "/cboard/titlelist";
}

@RequestMapping("/listPage", method=RequestMethod.GET)   
    public String listPage(Model model, Criteria cri, HttpServletRequest 
    req) throws Exception{
        req.getSession().getAttribute("clientMemberVO");

    List<CustomerBoardVO> list = service.listCriteria(cri);

    model.addAttribute("list", list); 

       PageMaker maker = new PageMaker();
          maker.setCri(cri);
          maker.setTotalCount(service.countPaging());

    model.addAttribute("pageMaker", maker);
    return "/cboard/titlelist";
}
```

Comment: Maybe, you should add method = RequestMethod.GET to RequestMapping

Comment: Do both of these methods appear in the same file, as your code implies?  Are you certain that you have done a rebuild and deployment after perhaps adding the second `/listPage` endpoint?

Comment: @Frank.Dai But that wouldn't seem to explain why one works and the other does not.

Comment: @wannadeve Are you sure that the first page you see is the page you want, not the default page or anything else

Comment: yes the page I executed first is what i want. Why second one is not possible. i'm sad!!

Comment: I don't think your program can be compiled. '@RequestMapping' must be
of the form 'name=value'.

Answer (score 0):

There was an error in the code and its not properly build I guess.
since in the second method, the model and req objects are not found in parameters , but inside that listPage method its been used. That is a compilation issue.

Please check the code again and its build properly.

Comment: For a Get Request, you cannot pass any entity. You are passing Criteria

Comment: If you want to pass, change as POST/PUT request

Comment: Criteria will get a '{}',That's not the problem.

Answer (score 0):

What is your `server name` ? And maybe you are not very clear the composition of the URL, like `scheme://host:port/path?query`. I want you to know that `path` including the `server name` and other parts. `"/listPage", "/cboard"` in your controller are all belong to `other parts`. But the url you want to visit is `http://localhost:8091/cboard`, if you sure it could be visited, I guess your server name is 'cboard'. In this case if you want visit `/listPage`, you should visit `http://localhost:8091/cboard/listPage`,you can have a try~
ps: If you are clear on the composition of the URL, you might be very easy to solve such problems as 404

Comment: thanks, but 'http://localhost:8091/cboard/listPage' is not possible and I use tomcat 8.5